# Share TCPClient Between Two Threads

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a service that needs to share a TCPClient between a listener thread and a writer thread.  What is the best way to ensure that if the network connection becomes unstable or encounters an exception on either thread, that the TCPClient is reset for both threads?

Comment: According to the documentation for the NetworkStream class: `Read and write operations can be performed simultaneously on an instance of the NetworkStream class without the need for synchronization. As long as there is one unique thread for the write operations and one unique thread for the read operations, there will be no cross-interference between read and write threads and no synchronization is required.`

Comment: Why not a boolean `tcpClientIsStable` flag shared between threads? Wrap it in a `lock` statement and update it accordingly. Check the flag before reading or writing.

Comment: Your reader thread should always be reading from the socket except when it's queuing data it just received, so a broken connection will be detected more or less immediately. The writer thread should always be waiting on a couple events, one meaning there's data to sand, the other meaning that it's time to shutdown, which is triggered from the reader when the connection dies. That's the gist anyway. If you use async API's, then there are additional synchronization methods available, and the idea of actual dedicated threads kind of goes away.

Comment: glenebob - Can you point me to an example using async APIs for this type of thing?